# Python manage.py migrate error when changing database from sqlite to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I just started learning django. I change the following settings from setting.py because I want to use mysql not sqlite:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backend.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'newprj',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'abcd',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : ''
    }
}
```

then when I try this code `python manage.py migrate` on cmd. It throws an big error, I can't understand what is the problem, please help me solve it. This is the error:
[image]

Comment: i think you should change `backend` to `backends` in `Engine`

Comment: better you copy and paste rather than take screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the **s** in `django.db.backends.mysql`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',    #<---- You missed the s in backends
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```